# How to get SSH access back to a user from which I accidentally stole ownership of `~/.ssh/`?

Tags: ssh, security

I set up an Ubuntu 18.04 server at the office from home, with two users `admin` (sudoer) and `pierre` (not sudoer). While setting up the server, I accidentally changed ownership of `/home/admin/.ssh` to `pierre:pierre` from `admin`, and logged out.

Now, I still have SSH access to `pierre`, but I am locked out of `admin`. Indeed, I was accessing the server by having my public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and `PasswordAuthentication` is disabled.

Can I somehow leverage my ownership of `/home/admin/.ssh` from `pierre` to recover SSH access to `admin`? I cannot go to the office and access the server physically because of the coronavirus epidemic.

Comment: So can `pierre` still log in via ssh? once logged in, can `pierre` execute `su - admin` for example?

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the presumption that you did not create the `admin` account locked, or explicitly lock it, and that it has a password that you know:

1. SSH in as `pierre`.
2. Switch user to `admin` with the `admin` account's password.

   ```
   su admin
   ```
3. Rename `~admin/.ssh` out of the way to (say) `~admin/.ssh-pierre`.

   ```
   mv -i ~/.ssh{,-pierre}
   ```
4. Create a new `~admin/.ssh` owned by `admin`.

   ```
   install -d -m 0700 ~/.ssh
   ```
5. Carefully move the relevant files from `~admin/.ssh-pierre/*` to `~admin/.ssh/`, checking that that Pierre chap hasn't placed any further boobytraps therein.
6. Remove `~admin/.ssh-pierre/` according to taste.

   ```
   rmdir ~/.ssh-pierre
   ```
7. *Before logging out of this session*, test a second SSH login direct to `admin`.

Comment: Thanks! As you proposed, switching to the `admin` user through local password authentication worked as expected, and I was able "chown" `/home/admin/.ssh/` easily after that.